# how to convert String to Text (Encrypted)

Tags: encryption

I have added few field in the Account Object lets say I want to convert this field account_field1 text(100) to account_field1 Text( Encrypted(100))

How can I convert it Salesforce do not display encrypted field when it is data type change button is pressed any solution will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the relevant information about best practices from documentation: [Classic Encryption for Custom Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm&type=0)

> Existing custom fields cannot be converted into encrypted fields nor can encrypted fields be converted into another data type. To encrypt the values of an existing (unencrypted) field, export the data, create an encrypted custom field to store that data, and import that data into the new encrypted field.

Comment: Apparently this is not true , I could connect the Salesforce through eclipse and modify the Object/Field  definition  where it change the data type to Encrypted . Downside is it is deleting all the data of the column

Comment: It might be possible but as you know not the recommended way as mentioned in best practices; hence you lose the data. ;)